# How to access a ViewState value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am populating a ViewState variable with the results of a DataSet.  When a user clicks a button in a gridview, it sends an index value to a method which I want to use to lookup values in my ViewState variable.

I have created a List to enumerable through my ViewState rows and have assigned the value of the ViewState to the List.  However, when I try to enumerate, I get a null reference exception.

My questions are

1. What type do I need for my List
2. How do I get the row index
3. How do I get the Zip value?

DataSet Columns:

```
Address1
Address2
City
State
Zip
```

ViewState:

```
ViewState["LocationsList"] = ds.Tables[0];  //DataSet type
```

Method:

```
protected void gvwCustomerLocation_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    int indexValue = e.NewEditIndex;  

    var test = ViewState["LocationsList"];
    string zipCode = string.empty;

    foreach (var item in test as List<DataSet>) //I get the null reference exception here
    {
        if(item.Row[index] == indexValue)  //pseudo code for wanting to get the correct row
        {
              zipCode = item.Zip;  //pseudo code for assigning zipCode
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `ds.Tables[0]` will give you a `DataTable`, not a `List<DataSet>`, your code should be `DataTable test = (DataTable)ViewState["LocaltionsList"];`

Comment: You are storing single datatable in viewstate and trying to retrieve `List<DataSet>`. That's the issue.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto When I change the test type to DataTable, I cannot iterate test.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  When I change the test type to DataTable, I cannot iterate test

Comment: Disregard my comment about iterating test.  I figured out how to do this.  Thanks for your help.